# When I switch from "Debug" to "Release" configuration, #include files cannot be found

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, release

The Visual Studio 2019 C compiler finds #include files when in "Debug" mode but, when I switch to "Release" mode, the same include files are not seen by the compiler, which generates a compile error.

Answer (score 4):

It's always best include the the text of the actual error.

My guess is that you set an "Additional Include Directory" in your Project settings, but you did so for just the "current" configuration. You need to make sure you do it for *All configurations* and *All platforms*.

[image]

Comment: No results. Theyre still red @@

Comment: But does it BUILD?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set include path for both build modes? Check entries in debug configuration and compare with release configuretion.

Answer (score 0):

In may case, I found that in | Configuration Properties > General > C++ Language Standard |, settings were different. Generally it will be a good idea to set | Configuration | in the above toolset to All Configurations